# Can anyone please help me to understand what does "well-defined" mean in the definition of Set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

We know that

> A set is a well-defined collection of distinct objects, considered as
> an object in its own right.

Can anyone please help me to understand  what does **well-defined** mean?

Let's say $X = \{ 1 , 2 , 3 , \tan \frac{\pi}{2} \}$.

Is $X$ a set ? $\tan x$ tends to infinity when   $x \in (0 , \frac{\pi}{2})$    and $x$ tends to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. And $\tan x$ tends to minus infinity when   $x \in ( \frac{\pi}{2} , \pi )$    and $x$ tends to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. But we do not have any concrete idea about $\tan \frac{\pi}{2}$. So it is undefined. So $X$ can not be called a set. Am I correct ?

Comment: Where is this quote block from?  It looks like an attempt to define a set, but I always learned that `set` is a primitive that isn't defined.   Of course, you can always give sentences that try to convey the natural meaning of a concept, but then one needn't go digging too deeply about the terms used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Well-defined" means that the definition indeed specifies one and only one object.

For example

- Let $n$ be the even prime.

  This makes $n$ well-defined, because there is exactly one even prime, $2$.
- Let $n$ be the prime between $24$ and $28$.

  This looks like a definition but is not well-defined. There is no prime between $24$ and $28$.
- Let $n$ be the prime below $10$.

  Again, this is not well-defined, this time because there are *several* primes below $10$. Note that by saying “the” you claim uniqueness.
- Let $n$ be the smallest composite prime.

  Again, not well-defined. There is no composite prime because the two notions “composite” and “prime” contradict each other.

Answer (score 5):

> Is $X$ a set? I think it is not because $\tan\frac{\pi}2$ is infinity.

Guessing your context, you are correct. I would technically say that, since $\frac\pi2$ is not in the domain of $\tan$, the object $\tan\frac\pi2$ is *undefined*.

(Unless, maybe if you have previously defined $\infty$ is as an object, and defined $\tan\frac\pi2$ to be
$$\tan\frac\pi2 := \lim_{x\to\frac\pi2}\tan x = \infty.$$
But you probably haven't done this.)

People say a set is "well-defined" to mean that there aren't any problems/contradictions/inconsistencies (like the above) when defining it.

Comment: One book said " 'Well defined' are not words of praise."

Comment: @DanielWainfleet what is that supposed to mean?

Comment: I guess that it's a joke.  Well followed by a past particple is often said in praise, e.g. "well done", "well played", so "well defined" sounds as if you are praising someone for doing a good job of defining something.

Comment: ahh, now i get it. thank you badjohn.

Comment: @Zest. It was in the context of defining the operation * as (aH)*(bH)=abH when H is a normal sub-group of a group G, when a, b $\in$ G. The author then explained that it meant that if aH=a'H and bH=b'H then (aH)*(bH)=(a'H)*(b'H).

Comment: thanks for your consideration @DanielWainfleet

Answer (score 5):

The term "well-defined" is not being used to refer to the domain of definition of a partial function (like $\tan$) here, but rather to the fact that not every purported definition defines a set.

A famous example is Bertrand Russell's set of sets that do not contain themselves:
$$
R = \{ x \mid x \not\in x \}
$$
Then if $R \in R$, this implies that $R \not\in R$, while if $R \not\in R$, unfortunately $R \in R$. Either way we get a contradiction.

The way we use sets nowadays starts with certain sets (*e.g.* $\omega$, the set of natural numbers) as given and defines others as subsets, and does not allow us to define $R$, so we avoid this contradiction (we cannot prove that a contradiction is avoided, but that just [a general feature of mathematical theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems) that can express enough arithmetical facts and for which the set of provable statements is computably enumerable, nothing to do with set theory in particular).

Answer (score 1):

It is well to notice that what you quoted is **not** an actual definition of a set in axiomatic set theory where sets are **undefined** terms with certain axiomatic properties. It is similar to the original definitions of Cantor who founded set theory. For example, a quote from 1895

> By a 'set' we understand every *collection* to a whole
> $M$ of definite, well-differentiated objects $m$ of our
> intuition or our thought. (We call these objects the
> 'elements' of $M$.)

This is similar to dictionary "definitions" of words
which use other word phrases in the definitions, but not
everything **can** be defined this way. There must be
first given a number of *undefined* words from which all
other words are defined. For example, what exactly is
a "collection"? The key concept turns out to be that of
elementhood. That is, it must be always possible to be
able to definitely decide if $m$ is an element of $M$
or is not, for any given $m$ and $M$.

Comment: Hello, can you provide a citation for this quote? I would greatly appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: Did you use a Google Search for the quote? What where the first two results returned?

Comment: The first page of results include a link to this question, 'mathdoctors.org', math-only-math, and youtube. I checked google scholar for "Cantor set theory" and set the date range to 1890 to 1900 and did not obtain good results nor a link to the original article. If you could provide the article title I would appreciate it.

Comment: @Gerald Thanks for that comment! The original quote is in German, so English translations have slight variations. I have used one of these variations. Also, the search should include double quotes for search terms. For example "we understand every collection" and also "of our intuition or our thought". These two combined should return good results.

Comment: @Gerald Also, the Wikipedia article about Cantor lists _Contributions to the Founding of the Theory of Transfinite Numbers_ as the primary English source of Cantor's set theory.

Comment: Thank you very much!